# Is there a C# equivalent to Foundation's 'withUnsafeBytes'?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app and part of that work is converting some Swift code to C# for the iOS solution (project to us normal people). I'm an iOS developer (don't ask why I'm working on a Xamarin project), so C# isn't my forté

I've run across a part that has me stumped.

Here is the original Swift code:

```swift
let firstByte = statusData.subdata(in: 0..<1)
let status: Int8 = firstByte.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Int8.self) }
```

`statusData` is NSData of which the first byte is a status code. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to perform the same byte operation in C#. I end up with strange results.

Here's what I've most recently tried (which I know doesn't work):

```cs
var firstByte = statusData.Subdata(new NSRange(0, 1));
var status = firstByte.Bytes.ToInt32();
```

Ultimately, I need to end up with a status value that I can compare to an enum.

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Can you write the in and output of the binary operation?

Comment: `(int)statusData[0];`